# Alerts working only when Delete Versions permission is checked

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, alert

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2010. Alerts are working only if the users have permission level that has Delete Versions permission. I want users to be able to get alerts, but not delete past versions of a list item or document.

Comment: Are you using versions/drafts? Are they trying to receive alerts on items that haven't been published to major versions, or haven't had content approval?

Answer (score 1):

They should be able to get alerts just fine without those two permission levels. What you should do is create a new permission level with the ability to manage and edit the document, but without the ability to delete.

1. Navigate to the site of the library at hand. If permissions are being inherited from a parent site, navigate there instead.
2. Site Actions -> Site Permissions
3. Permission Levels (in ribbon)
4. Click the "Contribute" permission level
5. Go down to the bottom of the page and click "Copy Permission Level"
6. Name your new permission level. I chose "Contribute - NO DELETE"
7. Delete the permissions "Delete Items" and "Delete Versions" and Click Submit.
8. Reassign the users that you don't want to delete to this new permission level.